# How to color cell with condition for bootstrap DataTable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-data-table-component

I am trying to create simple app to show data stored in Mongodb. I could get all the data and make it shown in the app. I want to set color in each cell of table when they meet certain condition. For example, I want any cell values over 50% colored yellow and  70% colored greed ... How can I do that? I am using MDB package based on React bootstrap 4.

```
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';
```

And here is my code:

[image]

and my app appears like:

[image]

I tried to find some solution from the documentation of MDB but couldn't find it that specifically change color by threshold.

Comment: Do you wish to target ***every cell***, or specific cells? The reason I'm asking this - not all of the cells contain meaningful numerical values (the ones you need to colour, I mean). Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you, and you simply want to colour the row, if one of its cells meets the criteria you gave. If that's the case, you could use a loop and `myVar.parseFloat.toFixed(2)` for cells in columns 3, 4, and 5, and then from that cell go to its parent, and apply a class to the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conditional styles in bootstrap datatable: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/data/datatables/

```
const conditionalRowStyles = [
  {
    when: row => row.coverage < 50,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      
    },
  },
 
];

const MyTable = () => (
  <DataTable
    title="Desserts"
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    conditionalRowStyles={conditionalRowStyles}
  />
);
```